# RadioButton with Button style XAML

Tags: xaml, styles, radio-button

How can I change the radiobutton style to a button style in XAML? And how to set the background color if the radiobutton is checked?
I would like to use the default colors (because I use differents skins).

Answer (score 6):

You need to define the controltemplate for RadioButton and apply a trigger in controltemplate. Something like.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CheckRadioFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And use it like.

```
<RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource ButtonRadioButtonStyle}">
            <Image Source="ImagePath\ABC.png"/>
        </RadioButton>
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Yes its helps thank you! But now, I want to add an image in my radiobutton (I want to use the same style for my two radioButtons but two diffrents images). How can I set the image as content on my style (on the button) ?

Comment: @Ben:- Editied the answer for you.

Comment: I find that the IsChecked property is not updated when the button is clicked. I have replaced the Button with a ToggleButton with the following definition `<ToggleButton Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>`, which I find works better.

Answer (score 0):

I often use this option

```
<RadioButton Height="23" Width="23" ToolTip="По левому краю" GroupName="TextAlignmentGroup"
                                                IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
    <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Image Name="ImageName" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="ImageName" Property="Image.Source">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="../../Resources/pressed.png"></BitmapImage>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="ImageName" Property="Image.Source">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="../../Resources/image.png"></BitmapImage>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </RadioButton.Template>
</RadioButton>
```