# how do I make a radio button with button style in code-behind?

Tags: wpf, f#, code-behind

I'm trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817638/radiobutton-whith-button-style-xaml) but in the code-behind only. Similar question, different target code.

What I'm trying is :

```
    let s = Style()
    s.TargetType <- typeof<RadioButton>
    s.Setters.Add (
        let templateSetter = Setter()
        templateSetter.Property <- Control.TemplateProperty
        templateSetter.Value <- 
            let ct = ControlTemplate()
            let fef = FrameworkElementFactory(typeof<Button>)
            ct.VisualTree <- fef
            ct.TargetType <- typeof<RadioButton>
            //let ct = ControlTemplate(typeof<RadioButton>)
            //ct.VisualTree <- FrameworkElementFactory(typeof<Button>)

            ct
        templateSetter
    )
```

which appears to work except the content of the radio button in this case `1` does not get rendered as the template button's content

Comment: Is that written in F#?

Comment: yes, it's F# `<-` is assignment. `new` isn't required. `typeof()` is `typeof<>`

Comment: Why do you need code-behind?