# C# WPF MVVM trigger change background color of button permanently

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to change the color of my button permanently, if the user clicked a button. How do I achieve that in XAML? 
The trigger I have right now won't work, because they are only temporary, not overriding default values.

Here my button template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonStyleNavigation">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF365B74" /> 
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
            <!-- <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>-->
            <!-- <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>-->

            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF658EAA"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF658EAA" />
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

**SOLUTION:**

So, I was able to get what I needed with the use of a `ToggleButton`. I've bound for each button one property to their `IsChecked` function. 
In my `ViewModel` I change the checked-state accordingly to my desire. (mentioned in the comments)

Here is my new `ToggleButton` template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="ButtonStyleNavigation">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF365B74" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />

            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="19">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF658EAA"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF365B74" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF658EAA"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF658EAA" />
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: this might help you... Toggle Button -
 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_togglebutton.htm

Comment: try moving triggers to style

Comment: @Bijan not sure what u mean.

Comment: Your triggers look fine to me, but I believe that they will only work if you apply a default value for the property that you're trying to set.  For example in one trigger you are trying to set the opacity to 0.3 so at the beginning of your style you should add <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/> otherwise it has no effect

Comment: @LordWilmore yeah true, but the opacity isn't my concern. It's just about keeping the new background color after a trigger changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a ToggleButton. They have a bool property called "IsChecked" that changes each time you click the button.

Taking the style you provided and changing it like so should achieve what you want.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" x:Key="ButtonStyleNavigation">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF365B74" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />

            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF658EAA" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF658EAA" />
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I have removed the IsMouseOver trigger as it conflicts with the IsChecked triggers.

When you say you permanently i presume this is what you mean. If you wish for the button to remain the same colour after a user clicks on the button again, you will have to deal with click events and check for number of clicks on the button.

**EDIT:**

As per your comment, if you want to have only one button enabled at time, look into using radio buttons instead.

[Here](https://wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html) is a tutorial on getting multiple radio buttons set up.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817638/radiobutton-whith-button-style-xaml/13818769#13818769) answer on how to style them to look like normal buttons.

You can then use the triggers in a similar fashion to check for enum values in your view model.

Comment: It is almost what I need. If the user is pressing another button the already clicked one has be IsChecked=false.

Comment: so, I tried to do this with the radiobutton.

But the styling part does not work how I expect it. Can you help on this? I update my question.

Comment: Your style looks fine, they appear like normal buttons. You now need to add more radio buttons to match your requirement and then data bind them all as demonstrated in the linked tutorial. Once you've done that, you can use the style triggers the same way as before.

Comment: I have to change the apperiance as normal buttons. But they won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure `xaml` answer, using a `ControlTemplate` as requested, taking your original question and just changing the `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` section:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Yellow" Duration="0"/>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF658EAA" Duration="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

In your original question you had (perhaps unintentionally) triggered from the mouse over event, in which case change here the `RoutedEvent` accordingly.

NB. You may be able to find an alternative to ColourAnimation with a zero duration, but I thought I'd post this as it at least gives you something to work with.

Comment: If I press one button, the other buttons have to get a specific background color.
With your code, the other buttons keep their background color. 

That's not what I need, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, if any button (with this template assigned) is clicked then they should all change colour, or should all of the other buttons change colour but not this one?

Comment: So, the first idea was to have a template, that changes the clicked buttons background color to a specific color AND changes the color of all other buttons assigned to that template to a default background color. The purpose is, that those buttons are for navigation purpose. If you press one of those buttons, you have to be able to see "where" you are right now.